# System call-validating addresses

Tags: system-calls, mmu

Let's consider the following system call made by the function

`size_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbytes);` from  `unistd.h`.

As I understand, the OS will validate that the process who made system call is permitted to access the supplied address of where to put the read data, namely `void *buf`. But why is it so? Is the address provided a physical address since it needs to do this check? If yes, is the address translated by the MMU to a physical address before doing the system call?
And how could a process supply an address it was not permitted to access? I can't see how a virtual address in a process' address space can be translated to a physical address it is not permitted to access.